# need help implementing argv to some source

Tags: c++

i have this Stealth Injector source from internet

so this program is for injecting .dll to an .exe

this program was made by someone to used for cheating in online game

but i need to use this program in my private server game online to tell the game client .exe the server IP, that is stored in a dll file..

the problem is i don't want the player to directly execute this program, but they need to run the game launcher first to do the patch..

so i need to put some secret parameter argument that will block player from direct execute..

i know nothing about c++

i only know that you need to use main(int argc, char *argv[])

i've try to put something like this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    stringstream sparam;
    string param;
    sparam << argv[1];
    sparam >> param;
    if(argc < 1){
        MessageBox(0, "Do not run this program directly, use the Game Launcher!", "Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        close;
    }
    if(param != "somesecretargument"){
        MessageBox(0, "Do not run this program directly, use the Game Launcher!", "Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        close;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code above works fine but the rest of code won't executed, it's just do the parameter validation and then the program closed..

this is the cpp and header file [Source File](https://mega.co.nz/#!Bc8CVTII!J3GfgAAP3Mf4RRAM47it_jxoaeFLPrG8h4Snw5Gxu2A)

Comment: what is "rest" of the code?

Comment: You should check if there are enough parameters passed before you index into argv.

Comment: It will be easy to get information about your secret parameter (via ProcessExplorer tool, for example). So it is not solution.

Comment: @Aniket i've uploaded the source file, the rest of the code is everything else except the main(int argc, char* argv[])
so it's just validate the parameter then close the program..not executing the game exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I figured out the problem. You have a `Win32` application, and although the `main` in it is called implicitly, if none defined, the control usually passes to `WinMain()` function, which executes your windows app.

Here is the solution, and a patched `WinMain()` function:

```
int __stdcall 
WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow) {
        LPWSTR *szArgList;
        int argc;
        szArgList = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argc);
         if(argc < 1){
            MessageBox(0, "Do not run this program directly, use the Game Launcher!", "Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            exit(1);
         }
         if(wcscmp(szArgList[1],L"somesecretargument") != 0){
             MessageBox(0, "Do not run this program directly, use the Game Launcher!", "Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
             exit(1);
         }
    DialogBoxParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DLGPROC(DialogProc), NULL);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: i got some error sir
"1>StealthInjector.cpp(204): error C3861: 'CommandLineToArgvA': identifier not found"

Comment: @FredyRommy let me do it for multibyte string then

Comment: @FredyRommy, done, re-check (I don't have a win32 compiler, so can't test proof it at the moment)

Comment: @FredyRommy, don't forget to include: `#include <shellapi.h>` at the beginning

Comment: i still got error in CommandLineToArgvW
"1>StealthInjector.cpp(205): error C2664: 'CommandLineToArgvW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'"
i've include the #include <shellapi.h> on top of StealthInjector.cpp

Comment: i got the solution sir..
i change the GetCommandLine() to GetCommandLineW()
Thank You btw